# enclosing unit using virtual sequence

Tags: specman

I'm having the following problem:

I'm having a virtual sequence driver which type is `top_sequence_driver_u`.

In it's MAIN sequence I am doing a sequence (called s1) with keeping its driver to a bfm sequence driver which its type is `another_sequence_driver_u`.

Then in the s1 sequence i'm doing an item. So far so good.

The problem arise when i'm using the `try_enclosing_unit()` method. 
I want to get the reference of type `another_sequence_driver_u` from that generated item but actually i am getting reference to the `top_sequence_driver_u`.

How could i do this thing, using the virtual sequence but that my item will have the `another_sequence_driver_u` reference rather than the virtual sequence type

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reference to the driver a sequence was started on, you could just use the `driver` field that every sequence has.

Comment: Thx for replying. Though my intention was not that. the problem is when i'm using the try_enclosing_unit() in the generated item which was generated in regular sequence named S1 i'm getting as a result unit type of the virtual sequence driver. i want to get the reference of the BFM driver (another_sequence_driver_u) and not that of the virtual sequence

Comment: @RonS Welcome to StackOverflow! Commends of type "thanks" are generally discouraged. If you find an answer useful, you're supposed to upvote it and/or accept it.

Comment: I think @Tudor's answer still holds. The driver field of S1 should be a reference of type `another_sequence_driver_u`

Answer (score 0):

the try_enclosing_unit() can return only the unit that instantiated this struct (or the struct containing it), and in this case - that's the virtual sequence driver.

why do you have to use the try_enclosing_unit() method?